# Can someone check if my tf-idf weighting is done correctly?

Tags: tf-idf, information-retrieval

I have a collection of 15 documents, where the term *Smoking* appears in 10 of them and where the term *Health* appears in 2 of them.

I need to check the values of these terms after the tf-idf weighting in a Doc where the word *Smoking* and *Health* appears once each.

The results that I get for smoking is 0.875 and for health, I get 0.176. Are these correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The information you provide is not enough to check.
Besides the number of documents that contain a word, it is important to know how often they appear in each document.
Check out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) article on Wikipedia, there is a calculation example.

Comment: I have to look at a Doc, let's call it Doc1 and check the values of the terms Smoking and Health. In Doc1, Health appears once and Smoking appears once. So the term frequency of the term Smoking in Doc1 appears once. the idf is 15/10, and thus 0.176. Then I have to multiply the term frequency with the idf.

Comment: So, i this case:

1/10*log(15/10) = 0.0176

1/10*log(15/2) = 0.0875